# ggplot fill fails if group contains only NA

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting an boxplot using ggplot and the following data:

```
plot_data <- structure(list(group = c("a1", "a1", "a1", "a2", "a2", "a2", "b1", "b1", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b2"), value = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3)), .Names = c("group", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the following code:

```
ggplot(data = plot_data, aes(x = group, y = value))+
    geom_boxplot(fill= c('blue','blue','green','green'))+
    theme_classic()
```

This results in this error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3): fill
```

The error occurs because one group has only `NA` values. `ggplot` shows this group on the `x`-axis, what I like but complains about filling the empty boxplot.

I could fix it, by removing one of the fill arguments.
However, this is not really feasable since I use the plotting function multiple times inside a loop, in which sometimes the values of some groups are only `NA`. I know, that I could create the fill vector dynamically based on the groups contained in the data, but I would like it constant.

So my question is:

**Is there a possibility to use always the same fill vector, without any complains by ggplot? Like another aes option?**

Comment: You are specifying `fill` incorrectly. As the message says, it should be either a single values, or mapped in `aes()` in which case it should refer to a column in your data. In your case map it to `group` and then control the colors with `scale_fill_manual`.

Comment: @joran Thanks, in combination with Antonis answer I could fix it. I did not know, that it would make such a difference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
ggplot(plot_data) +geom_boxplot(aes(x = group, y = value,fill=group))+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: ...and then technically the OP would probably want something like `+ scale_fill_manual(values = c('blue','blue','green','green'))`.

Comment: @Antonis Thanks! And yes, with jorans addition it works like a charm :-)